# Visual Basic Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called, error

Tags: vb.net, email

I have this code from this question:

[Generate a PDF file as system.net.mail.attachment using Memory Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272203/generate-a-pdf-file-as-system-net-mail-attachment-using-memory-stream)

to help me create an email attachment in memory.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
Imports System.net.Mime

Public Sub SendMail(ByVal att As String, Optional ByVal filename As String _
    = "Attachment.csv")

    Dim sendMail As New SmtpClient
    Dim mail As New MailMessage

    Using MemoryStream = New MemoryStream

        If att.Length <> 0 Then

            Dim data As Byte() = ASCII.GetBytes(att)

            MemoryStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
            MemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            MemoryStream.Position = 0

            Dim content As New Net.Mime.ContentType()

            content.MediaType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet
            content.Name = filename

            Dim Attach As Attachment
            Attach = New Attachment(MemoryStream, content)
            mail.Attachments.Add(Attach)
        End If

        sendMail.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        sendMail.Host = "SERVER"
        sendMail.UseDefaultCredentials = False

        sendMail.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("UN", "PW")
        sendMail.Send(mail)
    End Using
End Sub
```

I receive this error :

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
>
> 'Public Sub New(contentStream As System.IO.Stream, contentType As System.Net.Mime.ContentType)': Argument matching parameter 'contentStream' narrows from 'Object' to 'System.IO.Stream'.
>
> 'Public Sub New(fileName As String, contentType As System.Net.Mime.ContentType)': Argument matching parameter 'fileName' narrows from 'Object' to 'String'.

```
Dim Attach As Attachment
Attach = New Attachment(MemoryStream, content)
```

at this line.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or use this

```
Using MemoryStream As MemoryStream = new MemoryStream()
```

Answer (score 3):

In your Using statement you are initialising the variable named MemoryStream as an Object rather than as a MemoryStream.

Try changing your Using statement from

```
Using MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
```

to

```
Using MemoryStream As New MemoryStream
```